# ogr2ogr Set Feature to Column Name?

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr

I'm converting PostGIS data to PDF via GDAL 2.0.2 with below.

```
ogr2ogr -f "PDF" mypdf.pdf PG:"host=domain.com user=me password=mypassword dbname=mydb"  \ 
 -sql "SELECT geom,  state_name,  sub_region, state_abbr FROM  states"
```

It outputs OK, but I can't seem to find the method to get the output PDF to display the state_name column in the tree and not just feature1, feature2, etc.

[image: output]

Working now:

[image: working]

```
ogr2ogr -dsco OGR_DISPLAY_LAYER_NAMES="States" \  
        -dsco OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD=state_name \  
        -f "PDF" \  
        mypdf.pdf \  
        PG:"host=domain.com user=me password=mypassword dbname=mydb" \  
        -sql "SELECT geom, state_name, sub_region, state_abbr FROM states"
```

Comment: Here is query thanks to @mike-t below:          ogr2ogr -dsco OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD=state_name -f "PDF" mypdf.pdf PG:"host=domain.com user=me password=mypassword dbname=mydb" -sql "SELECT geom, state_name, sub_region, state_abbr FROM states"

Comment: Full query to display name of layer and tree display:       ogr2ogr -dsco OGR_DISPLAY_LAYER_NAMES=STATES -dsco OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD=state_name  -f "PDF" mypdf.pdf PG:"host=domain.com user=me password=mypassword dbname=mydb" -sql "SELECT geom, state_name, sub_region, state_abbr FROM states"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [PDF driver documentation](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html), you should be able to set a dataset creation option:

```
-dsco OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD=state_name
```

You can even modify the "sql_statement" label to something else with adding another option:

```
-dsco OGR_DATASOURCE="States"
```

The order of these options are important, where the full working command is:

```
ogr2ogr -dsco OGR_DISPLAY_LAYER_NAMES="States" \
        -dsco OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD=state_name \
        -f "PDF" \
        mypdf.pdf \
        PG:"host=domain.com user=me password=mypassword dbname=mydb" \
        -sql "SELECT geom, state_name, sub_region, state_abbr FROM states"
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this initially (sorry for not mentioning) and it returns "layer names ignored in combination with -sql."

Comment: Ah! - It needs to come at the beggining:    ogr2ogr  -dsco OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD=state_name -f "PDF" mypdf.pdf PG:"host=domain.com user=me password=mypassword dbname=mydb" -sql "SELECT geom, state_name, sub_region, state_abbr FROM states"  Thank you!!!